# Unpermitted parameter on has_one and belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to update a `@user.profile` (with differents solutions) but get unpermitted parameters or Profile User must exist.

But in my erb console :

```
[3] pry(main)> User.first.id
  User Load (3.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> 1
[4] pry(main)> User.first.profile.id
  User Load (2.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Profile Load (2.2ms)  SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> 4352
```

What's wrong ??

```
{"_method"=>"patch", .... 
"user"=>{"id"=>"1", "profile_attributes"=>{"user_id"=>"1", "last_name"=>"test", "id"=>"4352"}}, "commit"=>"Update", "locale"=>"fr", "controller"=>"users", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"ben"}
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id]
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id]

    if @user.update_without_password(user_params)
      bypass_sign_in(@user)
      redirect_to edit_user_path(@user.slug), notice: t('users.user_updated')
    else
      flash.alert = "#{@user.errors.full_messages.join(', ')}"
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit (
                  :id,
                  :email,
                  :pseudo,
                  :password,
                  :password_confirmation,
                  :current_password,
                  profile_attributes: %i[
              id
              user_id]
    )
  end 
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :profile, inverse_of: :user, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
end
```

**profile.rb**

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
  attr_accessor :user
end
```

**form**

```
    <%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.input :id,  input_html: { value: @user.id } %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :profile do |profile| %>
      <%= profile.input :user_id,  input_html: { value: @user.id } %>
      <%= profile.input :id,  input_html: { value: @user.profile.id } %>
  <% end %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The params of your form seem a bit off. Are you sure this is what is being sent? 1) id=>"Ben" seems wrong, unless you've made customizations in the table primary_key. 2) the params should be `user: { profile_attributes: {...} }` not `user: { profile: {...} }`. 3) You don't need to pass user_id inside the fields_for block, it is added automatically, you might actually be messing something up. 4) Do you have any relevant validations? 5) What does the actual unpermitted parameter error say?

Comment: 1: It's a friendly_id, 2: It's a mistake, I have badly copied 3: It's for the debug, 4: Any validation 5: Now, it's not an unpermitted parameter, but @errors=[#<ActiveModel::NestedError attribute=profile.user, type=blank, options={:message=>:required}>]

Comment: It is known bug: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25198 You can add `optional: true`

Comment: @mechnicov you save my day ;) Thks